# Equivalent to Excel 2013's 'BeforeSave' for Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to have a housekeeping macro run when an Excel sheet is saved, but I can only find reference to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx for Excel 2013.

Does an equivalent exist for 2010, or is there another way to accomplish this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

That workbook event is available in 2010 also.

MSDN 2010 link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: The MSDN documentation explicitly states it's for Office 2013 and later. I have tried the sample code and it does not run in 2010.

Comment: I have added the MSDN 2010 link in the Answer Post.  About the code is not working issue, it depends on where you applied that code.  Have you applied it in This workbook Code Module or somewhere else?